# How to call taglib method inside a column in list view?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a taglib method written in taglib.groovy. I want to use that method in one of the columns inside my list view of objects.

How should I approach that?

Comment: Are you using scaffolding?

Comment: No!! Does it matter whether I am using scaffolding or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it like any other taglib method:

```
<g:myTag />
```

Or if you're passing attributes:

```
<g:myTag attr1="Attr1" attr2="Attr2" />
```

Unless you've used a different namespace in the taglib then use that in the call:

```
<myNameSpace:myTag attr1="Attr1" attr2="Attr2" />
```

To call from a controller using the g namespace:

```
g.myTag( attr1: 'Attr1', attr2: 'Attr2' )
```

Or for a custom tag lib using Grails 3:

```
myNameSpace.myTag( attr1: 'Attr1', attr2: 'Attr2' )
```

Another way to access:

```
def myTagLib = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean( 'com.MyTagLib' )
myTagLib.myTag( attr1: 'Attr1', attr2: 'Attr2' )
```

Comment: I have called it like <myNameSpace:myTag bean="{Attr1}" name="Attr2" /> in my gsp file. I want to know how we can do it in any groovy file. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean how you can call it from e.g. a controller?

Comment: Yes I mean calling from any other groovy file such as a controller, listDataSource, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Mike W. This helps a lot. One more clarification, what is def myTagLib for? I am confuse here as I have inputtaglib.groovy as a custom tag library in which I have a method called 'contactList'. What should I do if I want to call 'contactList' in another groovy file. Also, I have custom namespace called "myApp".

Comment: I've actually just tested with Grails 3 & you can just call the namespace & closure name as with the g namespace, updated answer to reflect, so in your case, in controller call myApp.contactList()

Comment: Would you mind keeping the earlier codes as well? I just feel that I might need for reference.